# C++ win32 ListView columns

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem with my code.
First,the essence of this code is to create a ListView with some columns, using win32.

The problem is when I try to add columns to my ListView and try to display it doesn't show me the columns. Here is my code, thanks for any help.

```
HWND function::CreateListView (HWND hwndParent) 
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;           // Structure for control initialization.
    icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);
    RECT rcClient;   
    // The parent window's client area.
    GetClientRect (hwndParent, &rcClient); 
    HWND hWndListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, "ViewList",WS_BORDER| WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,500,300,300,300,hwndParent,NULL,hInst,NULL); 
    return (hWndListView);
}

VOID function::SetView(HWND hWndListView, DWORD dwView) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the current window style. 
    DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hWndListView, GWL_STYLE); 

    // Set the window style only if the view bits changed.
    if ((dwStyle & LVS_TYPEMASK) != dwView) 
    {
        SetWindowLong(hWndListView,
                      GWL_STYLE,
                      (dwStyle & ~LVS_TYPEMASK) | dwView);
    }                 // Logical OR'ing of dwView with the result of 
}     

BOOL InitListViewColumns(HWND hWndListView) 
{ 
    char szText[256] ="test";     // Temporary buffer.
    LVCOLUMN lvc;
    int iCol;

    // Initialize the LVCOLUMN structure.
    // The mask specifies that the format, width, text,
    // and subitem members of the structure are valid.
    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM|LVS_REPORT;

    // Add the columns.
    for (iCol = 0; iCol < C_COLUMNS; iCol++)
    {
        lvc.iSubItem = iCol;
        lvc.pszText = "LOL";
        lvc.cx = 100;               // Width of column in pixels.
        if ( iCol < 2 )
            lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;  // Left-aligned column.
        else
            lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_RIGHT; // Right-aligned column.

        // Load the names of the column headings from the string resources.
        LoadString(hInst,iCol,szText, sizeof(szText)/sizeof(szText[0]));

        // Insert the columns into the list view.
        if (ListView_InsertColumn(hWndListView, iCol, &lvc) == -1)
            return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: The editor you used to type your question has a live preview, so that you see what your question looks like. Use it to verify, that you are using consistent formatting.

Comment: `LVS_REPORT` as part of `LVCOLUMN.mask` is not a valid flag, its a ListView *style*.

Comment: i remove the LVS_REPORT and still doesn't work

Comment: What is LV_VIEW_DETAILS defined?

Comment: LV_VIEW_DETAILS are defined as 0x0001

Comment: `LV_VIEW_DETAILS` is not one of the [List-View Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739.aspx).

Comment: As other people are pointing out, you cannot mix and match constants. The very important thing to know is that because of how the constants are defined, the C/C++ compiler will not catch you — your only option is to read the documentation and make sure everything is right yourself. What does the caller of `InitListViewColumns()` do if it returns `FALSE`?

Comment: if the function InitListViewColumns  return false the caller pops a message error and I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the `WS_VISIBLE` style when calling `CreateWindow` to create the listview. The listview and the columns are there, just not visible.

The buffer you pass to `LoadString` is never used because you never set `lvc.pszText = szText` so all the columns are named "LOL".

Edit: My answer applies to the code after it had been edited with fixes from the comments. LVS_REPORT is still not a valid LVCF_* flag but because it has the same value as LVCF_FMT it does no harm in this particular code but should still be removed because the code is technically incorrect.

Comment: A `WS_VISIBLE` style is by no means mandatory. The common pattern is to create the window, and then call `ShowWindow` on the returned handle. The real issues have been addressed in the comments to the question.

Comment: @IInspectable: If you take the code as is after the edit then it seems like the listview is broken because the parent dialog is empty but as soon as you add the visible flag you will see the listview and its columns.

Comment: No, it doesn't. There's still a `LVS_REPORT` assigned to `lvc.mask`.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yeah I see that now but it is not the real issue. LVS_REPORT=1 and LVCF_FMT=1 so the bad flag has no effect.

Comment: There's also a `LVCF_WIDTH` flag, but the width never gets initialized. Again, your answer doesn't address this, and still holds probably misleading information.

Comment: @IInspectable The code does lvc.cx = 100; and that is correct. I did run this code (after minor tweaks) and it does work. All the specified bits in the mask have been accounted for.

Comment: i run my code and i could see my viewlist the problem is that I couldn't see my columns and i didn't forget to add WS_VISIBLE  it just in my main cpp
btw i delete my LVS_REPORT thanks for the help